# Converting a char * to int

Tags: c, pointers, char, int

Hi i have the below code and for some reason am getting the error and can't seem to work out why.

```
warning: return makes integer from pointer without a cast
```

The code i have is:

```
long convertToInt(char *convert) {
        char *p = convert;
        while(*p){
            if(isdigit(*p)) {
                long val = strtol(p, &p, 10);
                return val;
            } else {
                p++;
            }
        }
    return NULL;
}
```

Comment: And why would you want to convert a pointer to an integer?

Comment: There's a code smell, its a `convertToInt`, meaning an int, not a long, which is misleading.

Comment: Could you show how you intend to use the `convertToInt` function? The answer may depend on this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NULL is a pointer, not an integer. It may be implemented as a #define that expands to 0 (the integer constant) or ((void *)0) the null pointer constant. If you want to return a value that means "an error occurred", you'll probably want to return an integer constant. Values 0 and -1 are traditional.

Even better is to returns a boolean status value for success/failure, and return the value via a pointer argument: `bool_t convertToInt(const char *s, long *value)`. See the standard library function `strtol` for an example.

Comment: `bool_t`? I guess you mean `bool`.

Comment: Yes, bool, not bool_t.

Answer (score 1):

Your funtion returns `long`. So change the return statement to:

```
return 0L;
```

One possible definition of `NULL` is `(void *)0` which is being converted to `long` when you `return`.

Answer (score 1):

The proper code would be, assuming `convert` is a string with the digits:

```
long convertToLong(char *convert) {
    long val = 0L;
    char *p = convert;
    while (isdigit(*p)){
        val = val * 10 + (*p - '0');
        p++;
    }
    return val;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is here:

```
return NULL;
```

where you return `NULL`, but the return type of the function is `long`.

---

Moreover your function is named `convertToInt()`, but it returns a `long`, which would imply a `convertToLong()` function name.